# Geometric mean of log10 values

Tags: normalization, logarithm, geometric-mean

I have the following series of log10 numbers:

```
1.845098040014260
1.778151250383640
1.845098040014260
2.146128035678240
2.079181246047620
2.204119982655920
2.380211241711610
2.278753600952830
2.176091259055680
1.778151250383640
2.113943352306840
1.903089986991940
2.041392685158220
2.462397997898960
2.146128035678240
1.602059991327960
1.903089986991940
1.903089986991940
1.477121254719660
1.812913356642860
1.903089986991940
```

These values were obtained in a study sample and the geometric mean obtained by the statistician is 97.61. When I do the inverse log I obtain: 94.32062176898941.

Unfortunately, the statistician who helped me is not available anymore. Could you please help me figure it out how he reached this value? Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

@Sextus Empiricus, I plugged in the numbers from my series in [this online Geometric Mean calculator](https://www.statskingdom.com/geometric-mean-calculator.html) and the output I got was 1.9746. Then I applied inverse log to this value using [this online calculator](https://calculator.academy/inverse-log-calculator/) and the value I obtained was 94.3206.

I'm not sure if this was the right way to calculate it.

Comment: The geometric mean is 

$$\left(\prod x_i \right)^{1/n} = 10^{\log_{10}\left(\prod x_i ^{1/n}\right)} = 10^{\frac{1}{n} \sum \log_{10} x_i} $$

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Although I followed this formula for geometric mean, I don't obtain 97.61 after doing the inverse log.

Comment: I can't reproduce your false result. I get 97.61. You will have to explain better how you got your result.

Comment: If you will plug in the original numbers, instead of the logs, into the calculator you will get the geometric mean (97.6091)
70  60  70 140 120 160 240 190 150  60 130  80 110 290 140  40  80  80 30  65  80

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The geometric mean can be expressed in terms of the arithmetic mean of the logarithm

$$\overbrace{\left(\prod x_i \right)^{1/n}}^{\text{geometric mean of $x$}} = 10^{\log_{10}\left(\prod x_i ^{1/n}\right)} = \underbrace{10^{\overbrace{\frac{1}{n} \sum \log_{10} x_i}^{\text{arithmetic mean of $\log x$}}}}_{\text{exponentiation of arithmetic mean of $\log x$}}
 $$

So the geometric mean of some set of values is the exponentation of the arithmetic mean of the log values.

The mean of your values is $1.989491$ and the power 10 of this number is $10^{1.989491}\approx 97.60914$

---

What went wrong with your computation is that you exponentiated the geometric mean of the log values instead of the arithmetic mean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't upvote due to low reputation but I edited my question and explained how I got the initial result.

Comment: @ioanaT I have edited my answer in response to your edit.